# How can I resize an image pattern when the pattern is draggable?

Tags: javascript, html

I used this [Resize an image with javascript for use inside a canvas createPattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960564/resize-an-imagewith-javascript-for-use-inside-a-canvas-createpattern) to resize the initial image, but when I try to put the same code in my drag/drop functionality, it does not work correctly (it creates a new image and when I try to drag it, it gets strange - see image below. the "O" has the image before dragging/dropping, the "P" has the image after dragging/dropping).

[image]

Here is the code I am using:

```
function photos_create_preview_image(element)
{
  console.log(element.id);
  if(element.id.indexOf("canvas") != -1)
  {
    var canvas = document.getElementById(element.id); 
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var canvasOffset = $("#" + element.id).offset();
    var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
    var isDown = false;
    var startX;
    var startY;
    var imgX = 0;
    var imgY = 0;
    var imgWidth, imgHeight;
    var mouseX, mouseY;


    var new_img = new Image();
    new_img.onload = function() 
    {
      var tempCanvas = photos_create_temp_canvas(new_img);

      imgWidth = new_img.width;
      imgHeight = new_img.height;
      //var pattern = ctx.createPattern(new_img, "no-repeat");
      var pattern = ctx.createPattern(tempCanvas, "no-repeat");
      ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
      ctx.fill();

    };

    new_img.src = SITE_URL + "/system/photo/cf_preview/" + selected_fid;

    function photos_create_temp_canvas(new_img)
    {
      var tempCanvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
      tCtx = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");

      tempCanvas.width = new_img.width / 3; //TODO: Figure out what this should be, right now it is just a "magic number"
      tempCanvas.height = new_img.height / 3 ;
      tCtx.drawImage(new_img,0,0,new_img.width,new_img.height,0,0,new_img.width / 3,new_img.height / 3);
      return tempCanvas;
    }

    function handleMouseDown(e) 
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        startX = parseInt(e.pageX - window.scrollX);
        startY = parseInt(e.pageY - window.scrollY);
        if (startX >= imgX && startX <= imgX + imgWidth && startY >= imgY && startY <= imgY + imgHeight) {
          isDown = true;
        }
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e) 
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        isDown = false;
    }

    function handleMouseOut(e) 
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        isDown = false;
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e) 
    {
        if (!isDown) {
            return;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
        mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

        if (!isDown) {
            return;
        }
        imgX += mouseX - startX;
        imgY += mouseY - startY;
        startX = mouseX;
        startY = mouseY;

        var tempCanvas = photos_create_temp_canvas(new_img);
        var pattern = ctx.createPattern(tempCanvas, "no-repeat");
        //var pattern = ctx.createPattern(new_img, "no-repeat");
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(imgX, imgY);
        ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.restore();
    }

    $("#" + element.id).mousedown(function (e) {
        handleMouseDown(e);
    });
    $("#" + element.id).mousemove(function (e) {
        handleMouseMove(e);
    });
    $("#" + element.id).mouseup(function (e) {
        handleMouseUp(e);
    });
    $("#" + element.id).mouseout(function (e) {
        handleMouseOut(e);
    });
  }
  else //You can ignore this - not relevant to the question
  {

    new_img = new Image();
    new_img.onload = function() {
      this.width /= 3; //TODO: Figure out what this should be, right now it is just a "magic number"
      this.height /= 3;

      element.appendChild(new_img);
      $(new_img).draggable({ containment: "parent" });
    };

    new_img.src = SITE_URL + "/system/photo/cf_preview/" + selected_fid;
  }
  console.log("new image: " + new_img.src);
}
```

I changed the code to:

```
...
ctx.fillStyle = "#BFBFBF";
ctx.fill();

var tempCanvas = photos_create_temp_canvas(new_img);
var pattern = ctx.createPattern(tempCanvas, "no-repeat");
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(imgX, imgY);
ctx.fillStyle = pattern;

ctx.fill();
ctx.restore();
...
```

And that part works but, now it is only letting me move the image from the bottom. (See image below)

[image]

Comment: Can you show us jsFiddle demo?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/allisonc/cpR5J/8/

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear the canvas before redrawing:

```
function handleMouseMove(e) 
    {

      ...

        var tempCanvas = photos_create_temp_canvas(new_img);
        var pattern = ctx.createPattern(tempCanvas, "no-repeat");
        //var pattern = ctx.createPattern(new_img, "no-repeat");
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(imgX, imgY);
        ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, tempCanvas.width, tempCanvas.height);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.restore();
    }
```

Comment: I still get a similar result. It sort of works if I move it before the save function but then it clears the letter as well.

Comment: @AllisonC can you post a fiddle? thenn I can debug!

Comment: @AllisonC I cant figure out what you are trying to do here. will you update the fiddle to reflect the error?

Comment: Try dragging it around and you should see what I mean. It only lets you drag from the bottom of the image and then stops you from dragging it further.

Comment: @AllisonC that is happening because the mouse moves off the element to the container and the handleMouseOut event is triggered. See http://jsfiddle.net/cpR5J/11/  I suggest you move your mouse events to the DIV and attach to the object you want to move from there.

Comment: Do you mean the "mattes" div? If so I cannot do that because each letter has to be able to have a different image on it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44996/discussion-between-tnt-and-allisonc)